# Best Practice for Expanding Divs

Tags: jquery, performance, html

I'm currently working on a solution to expand divs dynamically based on their content. I've pretty much got a solution sorted but was wondering if anyone could check the code to make sure its efficient and conforms to the best practices?

The [page](http://www.rockantics.co.uk/index.php/leftnavmiddlesbrough/rock-climbing-events-holiday-clubs-competitions) in question.

and the code is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
  {
   $(".row").each(function() { 
           $(this).height($(this).find('.topHeight').height()); 
            //Only shrink div if the user has javascript on.
    });

   $(".btns").click(function(){ //On click of the expand button    

        var el = $(this).closest('div[class^="row"]');//The Div Element to be animated.
        var curHeight = el.height(); //The current height.
        var fullHeight = el.height('auto').height(); //Temporarily sets the height to auto and returns it to the variable "fullHeight".
        el.height(curHeight); //Resets the height to the previous height.
        var minHeight = $(this).closest('div[class^="topHeight"]').height() + 10;//Gets the minimum height setting from CSS.

        if (el.height() != fullHeight) { //If the div is not at full height

            el.stop().animate({height: fullHeight}, 500);
             //Animate to full size.
           el.find('#open').html('Click to Read less');

        } else if (el.height() != minHeight) { //else if it is not at minimum height

            el.stop().animate({height: minHeight}, 1500, 'easeInOutQuart');
             //then shrink to minimum height.
             el.find('#open').html('Click to Read More');

        }
    });
});
</script>
```

It just looks a bit un-efficient to me but so far it's the only way I can get it to work correctly!

So just looking for a few pointers really,

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: You probably want http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems a little to complex for that functionality?

This is how I would do it if I understood everything correctly:

```
$('.row').find('button').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.shadow').find('.extra').slideToggle();
});
```

The rest is just CSS.

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M3tbe/)

Comment: Wow, I had literally no idea you could do that.. thanks!